# Is there an "onload"-similar event listener for new elements beeing added to the DOM in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, listener, dom-events, innerhtml

Does Javascript provide an event listener similar to onload that will be invoked if an element is added to the DOM via `innerHTML`?

I know `<body onload="alert('hi');">...</body>`. But it does only work in the beginning when the whole site is loaded.. Is it somehow possible to add an element via `innerHTML = ...` that triggers an event listener instantly that it contains?

It should look like this and it has to be an inline-HTML listener like this:

```
elementxy.innerHTML = '<b onload="dosth()">....</b>'
```

Comment: That method requires an *external* listener, but I'm pretty sure OP is asking about a method for an *internal* inline listener to be invoked

Comment: You could use a MutationObserver. That can tell you when elementxy's children change, like when you add new html to it. That listener can then trigger a different event elsewhere. But you do have to set up the observer before changing the innerHTML, so not as easy as just adding some attributes to the HTML you'll insert. Could you specify what kind of event? Could you just dispatch it manually after changing the innerHTML?

Comment: @CertainPerformance is right. It has to be an inline listener in an HTML-tag. I added that to the question.

Comment: I tried DOMSubtreeModified ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Events/DOMSubtreeModified but it causes an infinite loop as you cannot set an event listener in a specific div = > you cant modified anything unless you unbind first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *really bad hack*, but you can create an invisible `<img>` tag with an `onerror` attribute and a `src` that results in an error:

```js
const dosth = () => {
  console.log('dosth');
};

div.innerHTML = '<b>b content<img style="display: none;" onerror="this.remove(); dosth()" src="badsrc"></b>';
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

This is one reason why inserting untrustworthy HTML is a bad idea - even with `innerHTML`, it allows for arbitrary code execution.

Regardless, it's best to avoid inline handlers entirely.

Comment: Perhaps even have `dosth` remove the `img`.

Comment: "really bad hack" This is exactly what I wanted. The intention is to demonstrate an XSS-attack.